# Has Cantor's irregular enumeration of rationals ever been discussed?

Tags: mathematics, set-theory, cantor

Enumeration of all positive fractions recently has gained renewed interest (see the list below).

By translation invariance we can be sure that in all intervals (n, n+1] of the real axis, there are the same number of fractions:
#(n, n+1] = #(m, m+1] for all natural numbers n and m.

That is a matter of symmetry, independent of the method used for counting them.

Cantor's famous sequence

1/1, 1/2, 2/1, 1/3, 3/1, 1/4, 2/3, 3/2, 4/1, 1/5, 5/1, 1/6, ...

however has half of its hits in the first unit interval and less than 1/n in the interval (n, n+1]. This raises two important questions: (1) What are the precise values of the function f(n) = #(n, n+1]/#(0, 1] in the limit? (2) how can the deviation from f(n) = 1 be interpreted?

None of these question could be answered in MathOverflow or Math.StackExchange.

My question: Can it be that this topic has never been treated in the literature or in lessons on set theory, for instance in the first years of set theory? I don't believe this but could not yet find any evidence.

List of sites

What fraction of fractions does Cantor's famous sequence enumerate?
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362791/what-fraction-of-fractions-does-cantors-famous-sequence-enumerate

Relative abundance of rationals in Cantor's bijection?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708845/relative-abundance-of-rationals-in-cantors-bijection

Translation invariance
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.logic/OIrleZcHXW0%5B1-25%5D

Enumerating the rationals
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/D2UYGbt9Qh8

Translation invariance
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scivszfc/tt_qy_ymAgo

Enumerations of the Rationals - two methods
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/uudISZF3An4

Comment: Related: Robert Gray, [*Georg Cantor and transcendental numbers*](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Gray819-832.pdf), **American Mathematical Monthly** 101 #9 (November 1994), 819-832. I would expect that anything since 1994 having to do with your questions would cite this paper because this paper is well known and possibly unique for the topic. However, the results of [a google scholar search for papers that cite this paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=17042434717467968164&as_sdt=1000005) didn't show anything I recognize as being very relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I could not find anything related to this topic therein.

Comment: What do you mean by "the limit" here? Which limit? Cantor's enumeration of the rationals doesn't converge.

Comment: The limit here means the complete enumeration. Take the first n indexes and then let n --> omega.

Comment: As far as I see Robert Grays article is not about asymptotic density of the enumeration in a selected interval, and hence irrelevant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 2/3 and 3/2 come before 1/4, and then there's 2/3,3/4,4/3,4/2.

Comment: Sorry, but I would like to correct some mistakes.
1) Robert Gray's article does not deal with the topic in question.
2) Cantors sequence has been given correctly by Franz Kurz. See Cantor's collected works. 1/1, 1/2, 2/1, 1/3, 2/2, 3/1, 1/4, 2/3, 3/2, 4/1, 1/5, 2/4, 3/3, 4/2, 5/1, 1/6, ... where the sum s of numerator and denominator grows stepwise by 1, and for fixed sum the numerator grows stepwise by 1 from minimum 1 to maximum s - 1.